# GoogleMaps Swift Tap Marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've got this function here which manages to perform an operation whenever a marker is tapped. But I would only like this to work on certain markers, say markers that are contained in an array

```
markers_array = [GMSMarkers]()
```

Is there any way to have mapView function only perform on these specific markers?

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
            if let marker = marker as? ChosenMarker {
        if marker.touchEnabled == true {
            // Have to show which one is selected too.
            print("Hello")
            let setAsHomeButton: SetAsHomeButtonView = SetAsHomeButtonView(marker: marker)
            self.view.addSubview(setAsHomeButton)
            self.setupSetAsHomeButton(setAsHomeButton)
        } else {

        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can create a GMSMarkers subclass with a boolean like touchEnabled and in mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) you cast the parameter "marker" to your custom class. Finally you can check if the touchEnabled is enable.

Comment: @JuanGarcia I'll give that a try! That should do it, thank you.

Comment: @JuanGarcia I believe I've gotten it to work as it only pops up on chosen markers but is there a way to get the original didTapMarker function? Because this function appears to have overriden it.

Comment: you mean check if the marker is from your custom class or a class of GMSMarkers?

Comment: @JuanGarcia I've added my code. The chosen markers behave as I want them to but now when I click on the other markers they don't do anything when I expected them to just give back the marker.title as usual.

Comment: when you tap a marker that is not a ChosenMarker the func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) is not call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118477/discussion-between-juan-garcia-and-tryingtolearn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a GMSMarkers subclass with a boolean like touchEnabled and in `mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker)` you cast the parameter "`marker`" to your custom class. Finally you can check if the touchEnabled is enable.